# Why do the capacitors inside the inverter heat up?

Tags: capacitor, inverter, overheat

I'm having a problem with the inverters of textile machinery. The machine I work with is the Rieter brand Ring machine and the main inverter, the part is defined as 75 kw U1. 12 units 2200 uf 400 volt capacitor inside the inverter and sometimes  capacitors from the condenser block often overheat and then break.  When I replace the deteriorating capacitor, the fault usually goes away. There are 20 textile machine so each month an inverter is breaks. But I can't figure out what caused the heatimg. The inverter has fluid circulation and fan system inside and operates.

What is the function of 12 pieces 2200 uf 400 volt capacitors in the inverter, and do you have any idea why the capacitors are heating up?

Comment: It is called Loss tangent or Dissipation  Factor that defines the ratio of Watts of thermal power dissipated to VAR's of reactive power conducted by the caps. In short the current is too high, perhaps motors start/stopping drawing excess power

Comment: Were these ever replaced with the wrong type? What changed?  My guess, you bought cheap caps with high ESR and it is being overloaded on start/stop.   Pls specify exact p/n.

Comment: I have never paid attention to it until now, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why the (large line voltage rectified electrolytic) capacitors are heating up?

- under-rated inverter for motor load
- lack of <s>VSD</s> VFD control method to prevent surges.
- Unskilled maintenance on critical parts.

  - caps like batteries need to all replaced if in parallel like batteries in series in order to share the load equally.
  - not all caps. are created equal

    - they have life test temperature ratings of 1kh to 5k hours at 85'C to 115'C
    - they have different ESR ratings or  loss tangent that affects temp rise. Pd=I^2*ESR
    - the best e-caps only only come from companies in Japan and S. Korea.
    - electrolytic caps are like Lithium batteries and demand highest quality process design and materials for low ESR.

Comment: I can second this by virtue of repairing industrial controls for a living. Elects have a limited service life, and that is inversely related to temperature. Hot VFD's in a hot plant = caps rapidly fail (usually a few years but depends on many factors.)  I'd add this "cap changing" to the plant's list of preventative maintenance tasks.

Comment: TY @rdtsc I'd solicit an experienced EE to (re) design for a 10 yr life.  Rieter brand is high quality , shame to put low Quality inverter caps to power it

Answer (score 3):

By inverter, I assume you mean a motor speed control inverter or variable frequency drive (VFD). The VFD DC bus capacitors carry the reactive part of the motor current. If the motors have an unusually low power factor, they may not be adequate. Even if they are adequate, they may be the most vulnerable component in case of difficulty with cooling or excess ambient temperature. You should review all of the operating conditions including the motor nameplate information, the VFD nameplate information, operating conditions, VFD settings and VFD instruction manual guidance. You should examine the cooling air flow path and heatsink surfaces. You may need to establish a regular cleaning schedule. You should discuss the problem with the VFD supplier. It may be possible to modify the VFDs to make them more reliable is your usage conditions.